# get user country code in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to get the user's country code when he visits my website.
I am using this JS code and its working good but I need to use php.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
</head>
<body></body> 
   <script type="text/javascript">


        function geoTest() {
            if (google.loader.ClientLocation) {
            var country_code = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code;
            var text = country_code;
            } else {
                var text = 'Google was not able to detect your location';
            }
            document.body.innerHTML = text;
        }
        geoTest();
    </script>
</html>
```

I searched if google have a php api and it turned out that they don't. Any idea how can I get the user country code when he visit my website site? for example using his or her ip?

Comment: You could just use the JS API and then send what you need to PHP with AJAX.

Comment: @elclanrs could you please explain more?

Comment: I would strongly suggest GEOIP for this. It is a reliable way to filter and monitor web content based on geographical location.